# Two Inner join on the same field to get same data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, ssrs, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm developing a Report in `SSRS` for `MS CRM 2011`.

There is a table named `StringMapBase` which contains `Option Set` we have declared in different `entities`.
This table has `Value` and `AttributeValue` column.
Every option Set I have created in any entity, has the Value(which is the name of that) and AttributeValue(which is the name I have choosed for that option set) in the `StringMapBase` table.
If I named an Option Set, I should read the the name from StringMapBase.
Like this :

```
    select  
SalesOrder.new_Order_Code,
orderreceiptstep.new_NextFollow,
orderreceiptstep.new_realization,
StringMapBase.Value,
orderreceiptstep.AccountIdName, 
orderreceiptstep.TotalReceivableAmount,
orderreceiptstep.name,  

orderreceiptstep.DueDate,
orderreceiptstep.ReceiptStepTypeIdName,
StringMapBase.Value, 

from orderreceiptstep
inner join StringMapBase on (orderreceiptstep.OrderReceiptStepStatus=StringMapBase.AttributeValue and StringMapBase.LangId=1065)
```

It gives me the name of one Options Set.
Now, The problem is that I have another Option set on the same entity that should get the name of that.
It means I need another `Inner Join` Like above,  Like this :

```
    inner join StringMapBase on (orderreceiptstep.OrderReceiptStepPrioriy=StringMapBase.AttributeValue and StringMapBase.LangId=1065)
```

In the first  I Used `orderreceiptstep.OrderReceiptStepStatus` of `orderreceiptstep` table and in the second I used `orderreceiptstep.OrderReceiptStepPrioriy` in the `Inner Join` clause.

I want to Have These two joins on the same field, Like this :

```
        select  
SalesOrder.new_Order_Code,
orderreceiptstep.new_NextFollow,
orderreceiptstep.new_realization,
StringMapBase.Value,
orderreceiptstep.AccountIdName, 
orderreceiptstep.TotalReceivableAmount,
orderreceiptstep.name,  

orderreceiptstep.DueDate,
orderreceiptstep.ReceiptStepTypeIdName,
StringMapBase.Value, 

from orderreceiptstep
inner join StringMapBase on (orderreceiptstep.OrderReceiptStepStatus=StringMapBase.AttributeValue and StringMapBase.LangId=1065)
    inner join StringMapBase on (orderreceiptstep.OrderReceiptStepPrioriy=StringMapBase.AttributeValue and StringMapBase.LangId=1065)
```

This means `StringMapValue` in the first Should return something, and in the second Inner Join must return another thing.
How Can I do that?

Comment: Hi and welcome. In order for anybody to be able to help you need to provide some details. Here is a great place to start. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, you're right there.

It's easier if you use aliases. SQL Server needs some way to distinguish between the copies of the tables.

```
    select o.*, s1.Value, s2.Value
    from orderreceiptstep o
    inner join StringMapBase s1 on o.OrderReceiptStepStatus=s1.AttributeValue
    inner join StringMapBase s2 on o.OrderReceiptStepPrioriy=s2.AttributeValue
    where s1.LangID = 1065
    and s2.LangID = 1065
```

You *might* get better performance with a cte like this:

```
    with StringMaps as (select AttributeValue, Value from StringMapBase where LangID = 1065)

    select o.*, s1.Value, s2.Value
    from orderreceiptstep o
    inner join StringMaps s1 on inner join StringMapBase on o.OrderReceiptStepStatus=s1.AttributeValue
    inner join StringMaps s2 on o.OrderReceiptStepPrioriy=s2.AttributeValue
```

Comment: Great dude, It fixed my problem.